# How to error handling curl and mysql in python subprocess.run()

Tags: python, mysql, shell, curl

I have python script which uses subprocess.run()

getting dump file by `curl` and input dump file by `mysql`

```
cmd = "curl {0}/{1} -o /tmp/{2}".format(dir_name,file_name,file_name)
subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True)

cmd = "mysql -h main-rds.sfsadsafasdad.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -pXXXXXXXXXXXXXX mydbname < /tmp/{0}".format(file_name)
subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True)
print(cmd)
```

For now, it works well, however it doesn't have any error handling.

- If `curl` fails I would to show the message and prevent from exec `mysql`
- If `mysql` fails, I would like to show the message.

What is the best practice for this purpose?

Comment: Just curios to know why you are using `subprocess` when there is popular libraries for [HTTP](https://github.com/psf/requests) and [MySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM If there is a possibility that the SQL script contains client-only commands, then it's necessary to invoke the `mysql` command-line client. The mysql connector cannot run certain commands that may be in the SQL script. Good point about the HTTP library though. Perhaps it's just a convenient way to do the http request and save it to a file in one step?

Comment: @whitebear, My recollection is that `subprocess.run(check=True, ...)` makes the function throw an error if the process returns a nonzero exit status. There are also options for capturing the stderr output.

Comment: @Abdul Niyas @BillKarwin, Your guess is right. using `curl` and `mysql` directly in shell is because it is the convenient and I had no idea how to use dump file in python's library `mysqlclient`.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I will try `check=True`!

Comment: I use `check=True` and solve this problem. thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("YourDBName", objconn.con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorID", 00);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorDiscription", "InValid");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However it's a bit defferrent what I need here.

Comment: Just attempting to provide multiple solutions to the users problem.